# file_get_contents Connection Timed Out for some contents

Tags: php, file-get-contents, connection-timeout

i'm developing a site in which user can upload pictures.

Once users insert the url ( only remote ) of image, i call a ajax to a php that take url and store it to the server.

The problem is the file_get_contents:

For some images it gives me Connection Timed Out, for other no.

Some images that gives me that error are:

- http://www.lloydsbaiahotel.it/images/bgtop/03.jpg
- http://www.lloydsbaiahotel.it/images/bgtop/04.jpg

I simple try to fetch content in this way:

```
$img   = "http://www.lloydsbaiahotel.it/images/bgtop/03.jpg";
$inbuf = file_get_contents($img);
var_dump($inbuf);
```

What could be the problem? Do i have to change some configurations of my server?

Comment: They could be blocking your request

Comment: Server is mine! Or you mean the server of the images?

Comment: the server of the images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use cURL , it gives you more options and control than file_get_contents as the following :

```
  $ch = curl_init ($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
    $raw=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
    $fp = fopen($save_to,'x');
    fwrite($fp, $raw);
    fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 0):

file_get_contents() does not deal with slow network connections or redirects for getting remote files. You can use fsockopen() which allow a custom connection timeout value.

You will get more info from [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php).

You can also use curl to fetch remote files.You can see [curl manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php) as well: